# Need SSL for specific pages using NODE JS for PHP Site

Tags: php, node.js, authentication, ssl

Hello my site was build by PHP and whole site had HTTPS Links, but i have two pages where am using nodejs in this pages communication is failed because of this SSL .Now what could I do to work on those two pages also.Please help me am struggling with this .Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you use two pages in nodejs? Actually it is not efficient. For example, if you have login system, you cannot read session information in nodejs which you have created in PHP or vice versa. If you tell actually what trying to do, we can help

Comment: i have two bidder and seller panels.On that i am providing communication between two panels by using nodejs.So just beacause of secure links this two pages not working I mean communication failed.SO what am thinking is to remove secure links from these two pages and provide through nodejs .. am not getting finaly what to do ...thanks

Comment: You need to make overall pages secured

Comment: My all pages already secured.But because of this my two panels communication failed.Before applying ssl communication worked proper.

Comment: Could you please describe communication thing further? In order to communicate, you need all page ssl secured. But, you say it is not working after you have applied ssl?

Comment: yup. here nodejs is running for only two pages But SSL applied to all pages including this two pages.I want to omit this https:// to these bidder & seller pages . I will appy through [following this](http://www.hacksparrow.com/node-js-https-ssl-certificate.html).

Comment: right now it is "http://"example.com:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js I want it like this "https://"example.com:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js But if i keep like this we can't able read socket.io.js

Comment: You are trying to read it from unsecured context? And you have setup ssl node js ?

Comment: But you cannot read secured content from unsecured content

Comment: that's the reason why i want to provide different SSL which will provide by node.js framework to these two pages.. But i can't able to figure that how can i omit these two pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution might it helpfull to someone. And thanks to Hüseyin for his time.

```
var https = require( 'https' );
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var fskey = fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/crt.key');
var fscert = fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/phptalen.crt')
var options = {
    key: fskey,
    cert: fscert,
    requestCert: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};
var server = https.createServer(options,app);
server.listen( 3030 );
```